# How to setup dockerized binaries in VSCode

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I have learned to use docker as development server (LAMP and MEAN) and now I feel I should take next step, By removing PHP and node binaries from system and use binaries from containers. So on a fresh Solus install, I setup containers for PHP, node, Ruby etc. Solus already recommends using containers for such tasks. But I got stuck on first day.

I installed vs code (Code-oss) on installed extensions (prettier, PHPCS etc) on it, and they need path of installed binaries (path/to/phpcs, path/to/node etc).

I initially set up configuration path as 
`docker run -it --rm herloct/phpcs phpcs`
based on https://gist.github.com/barraq/e7f85262bc7a0af2d8d8884d27b62d2c but using more updated container. It didn't work, So I set it up as alias thinking it would fool VSCode into thinking it is native command, but it didn't work either. I have confirmed that using those command directly from terminal does work, But VSCode PHPIntellisense extension does not want to work.
Any suggestion?

P.S. Any tip to keep container running in background as to avoid container bootup delay everytime I use PHPCS or javac from container? I can keep LAMP server running but everytime I enter terminal tools, it loads up new container to execute command, and then kill container causing delay for bootup and closing.

Comment: `Does not want to work` isn't a valid term for stack overflow. If you get some error log, people will be able to help you ;-)

Comment: I don't have an error log, I am adding path to phpcs from docker, in VS Code configuration, and it is not detecting it. Closest thing I am getting from search is vscode using node and npm from docker, Technically, I am doing same thing, Trying to call a utility which is installed in container instead of machine directly. By providing path to that utility which in this case is docker command.

Answer (score 0):

In case it is still relevant to someone: You might want to [create a VS Code development container](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/create-dev-container) to use dockerized binaries.

For this to work, a `.devcontainer.json` is required which could be as simple as:

```
{
  "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/typescript-node:0-12"
}
```

Comment: Just to add upon this, It will work on MS VSCode  binaries only, For linux users who mostly get Code-OSS from their package system, or those using vscodium or prefer their own build, This extension wont work for them.